# If PrintDlg is not recommended anymore, how should I show a printer setup dialog?

Tags: windows, printing

In my application I want to have a menu entry that allows the users to select the printer to be used and some characteristics of it (paper size, orientation, ...).

In the past I used PrintDlg for this with the flag PD_PRINTSETUP.

However, it seems that PrintDlg is not recommended anymore, and one should use PrintDlgEx instead.
But, PrintDlgEx does not support the PD_PRINTSETUP flag.  The result of the PrintDlgEx call is a dialog in which:

- the user can select a page range
- the user can select the number of copies
- there is a Print button

All of which are useless in a print-configuraiton dialog.

If PrintDlg is not recommended anymore, what is the recommended way of showing a printer setup dialog in your application?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `PageSetupDlg` for configuring the print page.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: No, the page setup dialog does not allow you to select a printer.  (I have the impression that these dialogs are a complete mess in Windows).